# Scipy Import Error with a 'Symbol not found: __gfortran_stop_numeric_f08'

Tags: matlab, scipy, python-3.9

I am getting an error when trying to import scipy in my Python venv. The full terminal commands/outputs are below. You can see that the scipy package was already installed in another terminal session within this venv. The error appears to be with some gfortran data type and the system looking for it my Matlab directory. I don't know why this would be or how to fix it. I am on a Mac. I tried these same commands on my Linux machine (which also has Matlab installed) and it worked fine. Thanks in advance.

```
mshafer@Michaels-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % python3.9 -m venv /Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv 
mshafer@Michaels-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % source /Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/bin/activate
(uavrt_venv) mshafer@Michaels-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % python3 -m pip install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.26.0,>=1.18.5 in ./Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scipy) (1.23.5)
(uavrt_venv) mshafer@Michaels-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % python3
Python 3.9.15 (main, Oct 11 2022, 22:27:25) 
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scipy import interpolate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 211, in __getattr__
    return _importlib.import_module(f'scipy.{name}')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    from ._interpolate import *
  File "/Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_interpolate.py", line 11, in <module>
    import scipy.special as spec
  File "/Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 649, in <module>
    from . import _ufuncs
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: __gfortran_stop_numeric_f08
  Referenced from: /Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: /Applications/MATLAB_R2022a.app/sys/os/maci64/libgfortran.3.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is arising because an incorrect libgfortran is being loaded. scipy is distributed with a vendored version of libgfortran. However, for some reason a libgfortran sited in a Matlab directory is being loaded. These kinds of problems can be got to the bottom of, but it can be complicated as there are various ways that shared libraries can be loaded, and the user can change how that occurs as well.

What is the output of `otool -L /Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-39-darwin.so`?

I would expect this to be something like:

```
scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-310-darwin.so:
    @loader_path/../.dylibs/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @loader_path/../.dylibs/libgfortran.5.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.0.0)
```

This means that the dlopen call should go up a directory, down into .dylibs (which is where the vendored libraries are placed), then load libgfortran from there.

Have you set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable?
How was Python installed?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have not set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I ran that command and got the following output:
```/Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9.   /site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-39-darwin.so:

@loader_path/../.dylibs/libopenblas.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)

@loader_path/../.dylibs/libgfortran.3.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.0.0)

/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)```

Comment: The output from this means that dlopen call should go up a level from the directory that the shared object is in, then go into the .dylibs directory, where it expects to find the libgfortran.3.dylib library. Can you see what the contents of the `/Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ/uavrt_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/.dylibs` directory is?

Comment: Also, how did you install scipy? When I install `scipy-1.9.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl` that wheel package uses `libgfortran.5.dylib`, i.e. version 5 not version 3. Did you install scipy via pip? Are you on Intel or arm64?

Comment: That directory has ```libgcc_s.1.dylib```, ```libgfortran.3.dylib```, ```libopenblas.0.dylib```, and  ```libquadmath.0.dylib```. I don't recall exactly how I install scipy, but it was likely with pip. I am on an Intel mac.

Comment: I think that all the libraries are where they're supposed to be, and they're the correct versions.
I don't know enough about how matlab interacts with a system to suggest any investigations down that line.
My next step of action would be to try to create a new virtualenv, and try installing scipy again, then try force installing older versions, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Oddly enough it is working now for reasons I don't fully understand. I wonder if this is because I was in the incorrect working directory when I ran the code in the original question. When I run ```os.getcwd()``` now that it is working I get ```/Users/mshafer/Desktop/PLAYGROUND/CODE_TOEPLITZ```. I didn't think should matter because of the venv, but do you have to be below the venv directory when you source a venv? I am new to Python and venv, so I am just speculating